# What is the difference between assign() and <<- in R?

Tags: r, functional-programming, global-variables

The normal approach to writing functions in R (as I understand) is to avoid side-effects and return a value from a function.

```
contained <- function(x) {
  x_squared <- x^2
  return(x_squared)
}
```

In this case, the value computed from the input into the function is returned. But the variable `x_squared` is not available.

But if you need to violate this basic functional programming tenet (and I'm not sure how serious R is about this issue) and return an object from a function, you have two choices.

```
escape <- function(x){
  x_squared  <<- x^2
  assign("x_times_x", x*x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Both objects `x_squared` and `x_times_x` are returned. Is one method preferable to the other and why so?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thomas Lumley answers this [in a superb post on r-help the other day](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-April/275905.html). `<<-` is about the enclosing environment so you can do thing like this (and again, I quote his post from April 22 [in this thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-April/275905.html)):

```
make.accumulator<-function(){
    a <- 0
    function(x) {
        a <<- a + x
        a
    }
}

> f<-make.accumulator()
> f(1)
[1] 1
> f(1)
[1] 2
> f(11)
[1] 13
> f(11)
[1] 24
```

This is a legitimate use of `<<-` as "super-assignment" with lexical scope.  And not simply to assign in the global environment. For that, Thomas has these choice words:

> The Evil and Wrong use is to modify
> variables in the global environment.

Very good advice.

Comment: Perhaps you should [link to it](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/What-does-the-quot-lt-lt-quot-operator-mean-tt3466657.html#a3466737)

Comment: thanks Dirk, I was concerned there was an evil application to `<<-` and this example of correct-ness and good-ness helps clarify the issue. Plus One for Mr Lumley

Answer (score 2):

According to the manual page [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/assignOps.html),

> The operators `<<-` and `->>` cause a search to made through the environment for an existing definition of the variable being assigned.

I've never had to do this in practice, but to my mind, `assign` wins a lot of points for specifying the environment exactly, without even having to think about R's scoping rules. The `<<-` performs a search through environments and is therefore a little bit harder to interpret.

EDIT: In deference to @Dirk and @Hadley, it sounds like `assign` is the appropriate way to actually assign to the global environment (when that's what you know you want), while `<<-` is the appropriate way to "bump up" to a broader scope.

Comment: Yes, but often you don't know exactly where the environment you want assign in is.  For most purposes `<<-` is the right choice.

Comment: @hadley I seem to remember reading that there was some consideration given to removing `<<-` from R as an operator.

Comment: Not a chance if you ask me as it would a ton of existing code. R doesn't usually strive to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @John in his answer, assign lets you specify the environment specifically. A specific application would be in the following:

```
testfn <- function(x){

    x_squared <- NULL

    escape <- function(x){
        x_squared  <<- x^2
        assign("x_times_x", x*x, envir = parent.frame(n = 1))
    }

    escape(x)

    print(x_squared)
    print(x_times_x)
}
```

where we use both `<<-` and `assign`. Notice that if you want to use `<<-` to assign to the environment of the top level function, you need to declare/initialise the variable. However, with `assign` you can use `parent.frame(1)` to specify the encapsulating environment.