# Filling data frame with previous row value

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns

I have a data frame that has 2 columns.

column1 has random numbers in
column2 is a place holding column for what i want column3 to look like

```
  random    temp
0.502423373 1
0.687594055 0
0.741883739 0
0.445364032 0
0.50626137  0.5
0.516364981 0
...
```

I want to fill column3 so it takes the last non-zero number (1 or .5 in this example) and continuously fills the following rows with that value until it hits a row with a different number. then it repeats the process for the entire column.

```
random     temp state
0.502423373 1   1
0.687594055 0   1
0.741883739 0   1
0.445364032 0   1
0.50626137  0.5 0.5
0.516364981 0   0.5
0.807804708 0   0.5
0.247948445 0   0.5
0.46573337  0   0.5
0.103705154 0   0.5
0.079625868 1   1
0.938928944 0   1
0.677713019 0   1
0.112231619 0   1
0.165907178 0   1
0.836195267 0   1
0.387712998 1   1
0.147737077 0   1
0.439281543 0.5 0.5
0.089013503 0   0.5
0.84174743  0   0.5
0.931738707 0   0.5
0.807955172 1   1
```

thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps you can make use of `na.locf` from the "zoo" package after setting values of "0" to `NA`. Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf":

```
mydf$state <- mydf$temp
mydf$state[mydf$state == 0] <- NA

library(zoo)
mydf$state <- na.locf(mydf$state)
#      random temp state
# 1 0.5024234  1.0   1.0
# 2 0.6875941  0.0   1.0
# 3 0.7418837  0.0   1.0
# 4 0.4453640  0.0   1.0
# 5 0.5062614  0.5   0.5
# 6 0.5163650  0.0   0.5
```

---

If there were `NA` values in your original `data.frame` in the "temp" column, and you wanted to keep them as `NA` in the newly generated "state" column too, that's easy to take care of. Just add one more line to reintroduce the `NA` values:

```
mydf$state[is.na(mydf$temp)] <- NA
```

Comment: I think this would be bad if there are already NAs in the data. But if it works that's good too.

Comment: @NealFultz, and that comment warrants a down-vote? It's pretty easy to address your concern about the comment. (I'm presuming that you would want the value in the generated "state" variable to be `NA` if it was `NA` in the "temp" variable. Notice that I don't touch the "temp" variable, so I still have easy access to that information.)

Comment: And if you have NAs next to 0s?

Comment: @NealFultz, ??? How should I know. It's not my data and these conditions are not specified in the question. I would still guess that a `NA` next to a zero should be replaced with the last known value, and with the current data set, I don't see that this would be a problem. Or do you want to continue filling the data with `NA` when an `NA` is encountered? Please feel free to share the condition you perceive and how you propose dealing with it. I don't see that your present solution handles `NA` values, so I am eager to learn.

Comment: Just to clarify, there are no NAs, so this solution did the trick!

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by the solution of @Ananda Mahto, this is an adaption of the internal code of `na.locf` that works directly with `0`'s instead of `NA`s. Then you don't need the `zoo` package and you don't need to do the preprocessing of changing the values to `NA`. Benchmarktests show that this is about 10 times faster than the original version.

```
locf.0 <- function(x) {
  L <- x!=0
  idx <- c(0, which(L))[cumsum(L) + 1]
  return(x[idx])
} 
mydf$state <- locf.0(mydf$temp)
```

Comment: Clever thought to modify `na.locf`. +1

Answer (score 3):

Here is an interesting way with the `Reduce` function.

```
temp = c(1,0,0,0,.5,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.5,0,0,0,1)
fill_zero = function(x,y) if(y==0) x else y
state = Reduce(fill_zero, temp, accumulate=TRUE)
```

If you're worried about speed, you can try Rcpp.

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
  NumericVector fill_zeros( NumericVector x ) {
    for( int i=1; i<x.size(); i++ )
     if( x[i]==0 ) x[i] = x[i-1];
    return x;
  }
')
state = fill_zeros(temp)
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, unless I'm overlooking something, this seems to work:

```
DF$state2 <- ave(DF$temp, cumsum(DF$temp), FUN = function(x) x[x != 0])
DF
#       random temp state state2
#1  0.50242337  1.0   1.0    1.0
#2  0.68759406  0.0   1.0    1.0
#3  0.74188374  0.0   1.0    1.0
#4  0.44536403  0.0   1.0    1.0
#5  0.50626137  0.5   0.5    0.5
#6  0.51636498  0.0   0.5    0.5
#7  0.80780471  0.0   0.5    0.5
#8  0.24794844  0.0   0.5    0.5
#9  0.46573337  0.0   0.5    0.5
#10 0.10370515  0.0   0.5    0.5
#11 0.07962587  1.0   1.0    1.0
#12 0.93892894  0.0   1.0    1.0
#13 0.67771302  0.0   1.0    1.0
#14 0.11223162  0.0   1.0    1.0
#15 0.16590718  0.0   1.0    1.0
#16 0.83619527  0.0   1.0    1.0
#17 0.38771300  1.0   1.0    1.0
#18 0.14773708  0.0   1.0    1.0
#19 0.43928154  0.5   0.5    0.5
#20 0.08901350  0.0   0.5    0.5
#21 0.84174743  0.0   0.5    0.5
#22 0.93173871  0.0   0.5    0.5
#23 0.80795517  1.0   1.0    1.0
```

Comment: I think `ave(DF$temp, cumsum(DF$temp), FUN = sum)` should work as well.

Comment: @Kevin: Yeah, you're right! In this case, `sum`ming the values works, too. And, perhaps, it is faster too, because it avoids turning to logical before indexing? Although, I'd still might prefer `x[x != 0]`, because it declares exactly what the `ave`raging function is.

Answer (score 0):

A loop along the following lines should do the trick for you -

```
for(i in seq(nrow(df)))
{
  if (df[i,"v1"] == 0) df[i,"v1"] <- df[i-1,"v1"]
}
```

Output -

```
> df
   v1 somedata
1   1       33
2   2       24
3   1       36
4   0       49
5   2       89
6   2       48
7   0        4
8   1       98
9   1       60
10  2       76
> 
> for(i in seq(nrow(df)))
+ {
+   if (df[i,"v1"] == 0) df[i,"v1"] <- df[i-1,"v1"]
+ }
> df
   v1 somedata
1   1       33
2   2       24
3   1       36
4   1       49
5   2       89
6   2       48
7   2        4
8   1       98
9   1       60
10  2       76
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the run length encoding functions, it's a natural way for dealing with steaks in a data set. Using @Kevin's example vector:

```
temp = c(1,0,0,0,.5,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.5,0,0,0,1)
y <- rle(temp)
#str(y)
#List of 2
# $ lengths: int [1:11] 1 3 1 5 1 5 1 1 1 3 ...
# $ values : num [1:11] 1 0 0.5 0 1 0 1 0 0.5 0 ...
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "rle"


for( i in seq(y$values)[-1] ) {
   if(y$values[i] == 0) {
      y$lengths[i-1] = y$lengths[i] + y$lengths[i-1]
      y$lengths[i] = 0
   }
}

#str(y)
#List of 2
# $ lengths: num [1:11] 4 0 6 0 6 0 2 0 4 0 ...
# $ values : num [1:11] 1 0 0.5 0 1 0 1 0 0.5 0 ...
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "rle"

inverse.rle(y)
#  [1] 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.5
# [20] 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0
```

Comment: You need some A-1 data sauce to go with those steaks?  :-0

Answer (score -1):

Simply use a loop with a global variable ,

globalvariable used here is `m`, `r` is a dataframe with two columns `A` and `B`.

```
r$B = c(1,NA, NA, NA, 3, NA,6)


m=1

for( i in 1:nrow(r) ){

  if(is.na(r$B[i])==FALSE ){

    m <<- i # please note the assign sign ,  " <<- "
    next()

  } else {

    r$B[i] = r$B[m]

  }

}
```

After Execution :
`r$B = 1 1 1 1 3 3 6`

Comment: First off, this is a really bad and un-R-like way to achieve what OP is after. There are much *much* better (and vectorised) alternatives, see the other answers to this post. Secondly, the code you give is actually not reproducible. `r` is not defined anywhere, you mention `R` as a `data.frame` but R is case-sensitive. Using `<<-` in this context is precisely one of the examples for how *not* to use `<<-`: [The Evil and Wrong use is to modify variables in the global environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5785757/6530970).

Comment: [continued] Lastly, `next` is a [control flow statement](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Control.html); `next` doesn't return a value, and it should be `next` instead of `next()`. I think this answer contributes little (if anything) to this post and therefore should be deleted as it promotes bad R coding practice.