# Scoping assignment

Tags: f#

I am still trying to get the mindset for functional programming, hence I am not sure the question is meaningful: is [scoping assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785290/what-is-the-difference-between-assign-and-in-r) possible in F# as it is in R?

Let' suppose I am designing a function `split x` when `x = y + 10z` for `abs(int:y) <= 5` and `abs(int:z)`.

```
 let split x =
    let z = abs(x / 10)
    let modz = abs(x % 10)
    let y =
            if modz > 5 then
                    let z = z + 1
                    abs(5 - modz)

            else
                    modz
    (y, z);;
```

Given a module of z bigger then 5, I would like to modify the value of z. 
I.e., for `split 27` I expect as result (2, 3).

```
split 22;;
val it : int * int = (2, 2)

split 27;;
val it : int * int = (2, 2)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `let` keyword creates a *name binding*, which means "this name means this value" (or this function). It is immutable: in the code you wrote, the name `z` in the `split` function will always refer to the value `abs(x / 10)`, and cannot be changed. The `let z = z + 1` expression in your `if modz > 5 = ...` block is not reassigning the value of the outer `z`. Instead, it's creating a **new** definition of `z`, local to the block that it's in. What the code you've written is saying is "within the true part of this `if` expression, I want a name called `z` whose value is the value of `z` that I currently know about, plus 1. Oh, and hide the "outer" `z` from me: inside this block, I want to use *my* definition of `z`." But outside the block, the "outer" `z` is unchanged. This allows you to redefine names at will, without accidentally causing bugs in other code, and it's usually a good thing.

What you're trying to do is create a *mutable variable*, and that's done by adding the `mutable` keyword to `let`. The syntax for assigning a new value to a mutable variable is also different: it doesn't use `let` at all. What you wanted is to write:

```
let mutable z = abs(x / 10)
// Later on...
z <- z + 1
```

The left-facing arrow operator `<-` means "change the value of this mutable variable". If you write `z = z + 1`, which is a common newbie mistake, the compiler will give you a warning that this is a Boolean value that is ignored -- because when it's not part of a `let` binding, the `=` operator is comparison. The expression `z = z + 1` is asking "is `z` equal to `z + 1`?" And that will always be false (unless you've created a really weird numeric type).

I don't really recommend using `mutable` as a general rule. Try re-writing your logic to avoid it. For example, you could write your function like so:

```
let split x =
    let z = abs(x / 10)
    let modz = abs(x % 10)
    let increment = if modz > 5 then 1 else 0
    let y = if modz > 5 then abs(5 - modz) else modz
    (y, z + increment)
```

That would be more functional, and avoid the use of `mutable`.

Comment: I am impressed. You just made me clear far more things then expected. Thank you!

Comment: Note that I just edited my example, because the final line was wrong. I originally wrote `(y + increment, z)`, but what I should have written to match the logic of your function was `(y, z + increment)`. Also, I left off the `;;` because you don't need them if you're writing `.fs` files. You do need them if you're typing code into the F# Interactive interpreter, though, so include the `;;` at the end of your code if (and only if) you're typing it into F# Interactive.

Comment: Yes, I noticed, but I got the point anyway. In any case, thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 4):

In F# the values (variables) are immutable, you cannot update the value of z.

```
let z = abs(x / 10)
```

And

```
let z = z + 1
```

Are different declared values, with different scopes.

The scope in F# is identified by indentation, so when you return

```
(y, z);;
```

You return the z with same indentation (`let z = abs(x / 10)`)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it is a really useful information for me!