# How to assign to global variable from a function when masking existing object?

Tags: r

I have function like this:

```
myfun <- function ()
{
    df <<- data.frame(a = 1)
}
myfun()
```

but it reports an error "Error in myfun() : cannot change value of locked binding for 'df'". I really need to modify the global variable df and I don't care if I mask existing function. How can I do this?

I discovered this solution. It works, but is there something less complicated?

```
myfun <- function ()
{
    df <- data.frame(a = 1)
    assign("df", df, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
myfun()
```

Answer (score 5):

The *best* solution here would be to avoid handling the scope of the variables inside the function entirely.  If you want to create a function which can be used to assign a data frame variable, then just have that function return the data frame:

```
myfun <- function() {
    df <- data.frame(a = 1)
    return(df)
}

# from some calling scope
mydf <- myfun()
```

If you want a data frame to be assigned inside a certain scope, then let that scope make the assignment, rather than having the function do this.

Comment: I know this is possible, I am not a beginner ;-) If that was a solution for me I wouldn't be asking :-) My function returns lots of other variables as well. Solution with `attach(myfun())` is unnaceptable, since it is in a for loop.

Comment: In general, if you need an R function to reach out and make assignments in some other scope, it can indicate a design smell.  You likely shouldn't have the need to do this.

Comment: That's idealistic thinking. Following it means long ugly code instead of simple elegant code... So this is a reason I am specifically asking about assigning to a global variable, this is not a solution.

Comment: @TMS No, that's *functional* thinking. How is the example given by Tim "ugly code"? I would argue it's syntactically cleaner. The bottom line is you should not assign to a variable in the global environment using `<<-` or `assign`. There are quite a few posts here on SO that explain *why* this is a bad idea. If you want to avoid copying data, perhaps an option is to use a (pseudo-) OOP system like `R6` or reference classes.

Answer (score 3):

There's not much to add to @TimBiegeleisen's answer; however, in response to your post and the error you see, you'd need to declare `df` outside of the function scope.

The following works

```
df <- data.frame()
myfun <- function () df <<- data.frame(a = 1)
myfun()
df
#  a
#1 1
```

Note however that this is *not* how `<<-` is supposed to be used, see [Dirk Eddelbuettel's answer to "What is the difference between assign and `<<-` in R"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785290/what-is-the-difference-between-assign-and-in-r). To summarise:

- **you may use** `<<-` to update an object in a parent (but not global) environment ("super-assignment" with lexical scope), and conversely
- **don't use** `<<-` to update an object in the global environment.

Comment: if a `df` object is found on the way up before the intended `df` object it will be updated silently and debugging might be painful